# Do i need to discover gateway service in discovery server?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

Do i need to discover Spring cloud gateway in Spring cloud service discovery eureka?

Should i request directly to api gateway and then api gateway will redirect to eureka and  then to the next servic.

Or

I should request to the eureka service discovery first and service discovery will redirect me to the api gateway and then api gateway will redirect to the next service.